# In CodeIgniter: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I get the above error with this code can anyone help ?

From Controller.php

```
public function upbHors() {

        $modele = new \App\Models\Modele();

            session_start();
            $modele->upbHors($_SESSION['idVisiteur'], date("F"), $_POST['frais_h'], $_POST['date_h'], $_POST['montant_h']);
            echo view ('vueRenseignement');

        }
```

From Modele.php

```
public function upbHors($idVisiteur, $mois, $libelle, $date, $montant,) {
      
        $db = db_connect();

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO LigneFraisHorsForfait (idVisiteur, mois, libelle, date, montant) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)';

        $resultat = $db->query($sql, [$idVisiteur, $mois, $libelle, $date, $montant]);

        //$resultat = $resultat->getResult();

        return $resultat;
    }
```

From the database

```
CREATE TABLE LigneFraisHorsForfait (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
idVisiteur VARCHAR(5),
mois VARCHAR(25),
libelle VARCHAR(255),
date DATE,
montant DECIMAL(10,2),
FOREIGN KEY (idVisiteur, mois) REFERENCES FicheFrais(idVisiteur, mois)
)ENGINE = Innodb, Charset=UTF8;
```

When you do `SELECT * FROM LigneFraisHorsForfait;` you get a id, idVisiteur, mois, libelle, date, montant who are all empty

Comment: `idVisiteur` and `mois` must match in both tables, `LingneFraisHorsForfait` and `FicheFrais`

Comment: Can you check if `idVisiteur` and `mois` are empty or not and also have the exact same existing reference in the table `FicheFrais` before inserting them into the table?